# HTML5 datatime-local input formatting error: "Literal did not satisfy local datetime format" using value from mysql

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to use the date/time value from mysql into a form with php.  I've tried various ways to convert the value to the correct format from examples I've found on line (single vs double quotes, etc).  But continue to get the error message with variations of this code.

```
<input type="datetime-local" value="<?php echo "$formatStartDate"; ?>" name="$reminder_start_datetime">
```

I've tried using the value directly from mysql and also formatting it like this:

```
$formatStartDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm', $reminder_start_datetime);
```

But it does not work.

I need to format the string in $reminder_start_datetime to be valid for an HTML5 datetime-local input.

Comment: Hi! How do you get the data from the database? That will determine what format the db date is in when you receive it. If it's a string (often the case) then `strtotime` should be able to make it into a PHP date.

Comment: This is not enough of your code to see anything other than there must be an issue before this code line.

Comment: Imagine you are reading this question for the first time like we are! Could you work out accurately what might be wrong

Comment: Please add more of yor code

Comment: Sorry about that.  Here is the previous code.

Comment: >if(isset($_GET['reminder_id'])) {
    $reminder_id = $_GET['reminder_id'];
    
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM reminders WHERE reminder_id = $reminder_id ";
$select_reminder_by_id = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_reminder_by_id)) {
    $reminder_title = $row['reminder_title'];
    $reminder_note = $row['reminder_note'];
    $reminder_start_datetime = $row['reminder_start_datetime'];

Comment: Sorry I'm struggling to post the code

Comment: We need to know the format of `$reminder_start_datetime`.  Can you do a `die($reminder_start_datetime);` and tell me what it outputs?

Comment: You click the _edit_ link

Comment: It is very unlikely to be `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm` maybe `Y-m-dTH:m:s` is more likely [Read the DateTime::createFromFormat manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: Current Start Date:  0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
input type="datetime-local" value="<?php echo "$formatStartDate"; ?>" name="$reminder_start_datetime">
```

to this

```
input type="text" value="<?php echo $formatStartDate; ?>" name="$reminder_start_datetime">
```

That will get rid of the error.

If you insist on using `datetime-local`, then don't use `DateTime::createFromFormat`, instead do this:

```
// tested with this value and it works
// $reminder_start_datetime = "2005-1-1 12:00 AM";
$formatStartDateStamp = strtotime($reminder_start_datetime);
$formatStartDate = strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%m:%S", $formatStartDateStamp);
```

Comment: Note I had the format string wrong.  It should have been a capital S for seconds.  Its been corrected. "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%m:%S"

Comment: copied in that could and still get the error with this input:

Comment: > <input type="datetime-local" value="<?php echo "$formatStartDate"; ?>" name="$reminder_start_datetime">

Comment: You get this error: "Literal did not satisfy local datetime format using php value"?  I highly doubt it.

Comment: Tried capital S.  Still getting error.  Really appreciate your assistance

Comment: The error "Literal did not satisfy local datetime format using php value" will only happen if you are still using DateTime::createFromFormat, which you should not be using anymore if you followed my code.

Comment: "literal did not satisfy the local datetime format"

Comment: Did you completely erase the `DateTime::createFromFormat` line of code?

Comment: Oh wait nm....  The error is an HTMl5 validation error.  I will revise my answer.

Comment: yes, I erased that code you refer to.  Only using your two lines of code and the input last shown above.   Sorry if title confused you.

Comment: In Chrome, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%m:%S" works for datetime-local (in the United States).  The format of the string will depend on your locale.

Comment: In any case, I think you should just ditch the `datetime-local` and replace it with a standard `text` and the error will be gone, per my revised answer.

Comment: I'm using Chrome too, in the U.S.  Could my input string be the problem?

Comment: The error is coming from Chrome.  It is saying the the format of the string you are putting into `value` is not valid.  If you change 'datetime-local' to 'text' it will make the error go away.  Then you can at least render the page and see what is going in there that is causing the problem.

Comment: That made the error go away.  I'll play with the formatting.  Thanks for your help.  Started learning PHP a few months and and picked up some.  But date formatting is making me crazy.   Thanks again.

Comment: No problem.  If this answered your question please accept the answer.